# Regular expression for finding contact pages

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to create regular expresion which could take url from `href` atribute if `<a>` would be named contact. I've created such regular expresion:

```
(?<=href=").*?(?=".*>[Cc]ontact)
```

It is working fine if every a `href` is in new line like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
<ul class="navbar-right nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="http://www.test.com/page1">Page1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.test.com/page2">Page2</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.test.com/page3">Page3</a></li></ul></li>
<li><a href="http://www.test.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.test.com/page4">Page4<span class="caret"></span></a>
</ul>
</div>
```

result:

```
http://www.test.com/contact
```

But if it's not so well formatted and more `href`s are in one line it's finding all urls and not only contact url. How can I fix it?

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation"><ul class="navbar-right nav navbar-nav"><li><a href="http://www.test.com/page1">Page1</a></li><li><a href="http://www.test.com/page2">Page2</a></li><li><a href="http://www.test.com/page3">Page3</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="http://www.test.com/contact">Contact</a></li><li><a href="http://www.test.com/page4">Page4<span class="caret"></span></a></ul></div>
```

result:

```
http://www.test.com/page1
http://www.test.com/page2
http://www.test.com/page3
http://www.test.com/contact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
(?<=href=")[^"]*?(?="[^<]*>[Cc]ontact)
```

Explanation:

```
(?<=href=") # look back for href="
[^"]*? #any character that isn't "
(?="[^<]*>[Cc]ontact) # look forward for any character that isn't a starting tag until find [Cc]ontact
```